# Send Email after Form is Edited

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google form that works great.  Inside that form i also have scripts written up that send out emails.  These also work great.

What i dont have is a way to make those scripts trigger and run on their own.  For now, when the form is edited, i get a notification email.  I then have to log into the spreadsheet and manually run my email script(s).

I want the spreadsheet to run the scripts automatically and send the email when data is added from the form.  I tried the onEdit below but that only works if i have the spreadsheet open and i launch it.  Is there another way to run a script automatically after a form is edited without having to open it up?

Here is a basic email code + my onEdit i tried to make work.

```
// Ran when the spreadsheet is edited
function onEdit(){ 
  emailEOnEdit();
}

// Sends an email when the New User Request Form is edited
function emailEOnEdit(row){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var subject = "Test Email On Edit";
  var recipients = "user@domain.com"
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>" 
    + "<P>" + sheet.getRange("E1").getValues()
    + "</HTML></BODY>"; 
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the [onFormSubmit trigger?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events#TriggerAttributes)

Comment: Thanks ScampMichael!   I never knew that existed.